# Fitting images to width

Tags: html, css, image, src

I have many

```
img src="xxxx" border="0" style="font-size: 11px;"
```

after another. But they all have a width that exceeds the maximum width of the table.

I was wondering if there is a way to `<.....>` them all in and give a single command to change all their widths without having to add the `width=800px` tag to each `img src`

I am not very good with HTML but i can figure it out if you give me the command.

I was trying `div.../divs` but I couldn't get it to affect them.

Comment: You could use css, and style the width that way.

Answer (score 0):

Use css class for it

give all the `img` a class

example may be

**HTML**

```
<img src="xxxx" border="0" style="font-size: 11px;" class="myImage">
<img src="xxxx" border="0" style="font-size: 11px;" class="myImage">
<img src="xxxx" border="0" style="font-size: 11px;" class="myImage">
<img src="xxxx" border="0" style="font-size: 11px;" class="myImage">
....
```

**CSS**

```
.myImage{

width:800px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="image_container">
    <img src="image.png" />
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#image_container { width:800px; height:500px; }
#image_container img { max-width:100%; max-height: 100%; }
```

If you try this the image will not be stretch and the quality will not get damage.
Enjoy.

Comment: I don't think I can use css..:(.. This is going into a table that is generated by a website.. For example, I am putting a bunch of images in a description to an ebay listing. (but not ebay) 

is there a way to put parameter on the div.. somethign like

div id="image_container" { width:800px; height:500px; }